# Unable to install pysal due to setup.py egg_info file

Tags: python, pip, installation, google-colaboratory, setup.py

I was working in colab. I wanted to install pysal module for my project. I got the following error.

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

The whole error log is shown below:

```
Collecting pysal
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/68/04/e9a456867aa2686186f7d1d1fd3c9598ac27a92d08063afa236a1f1fd7e2/pysal-2.2.0.tar.gz (104kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 2.8MB/s 
Collecting libpysal>=4.2.2
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6f/00/bf40b380e9064222868c93ed51d81dd14b1266b16dd5a54e53aaed12caf2/libpysal-4.2.2.tar.gz (2.4MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.4MB 9.0MB/s 
Collecting esda>=2.2.1
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/16/f1/c2190bc3a7ef9c83ce0b060b927763352bfc0a55ccea8bb5fcd8975de347/esda-2.2.1.tar.gz (62kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 8.6MB/s 
Collecting giddy>=2.3.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6e/96/c9cac4d3a00dbe682a4031e3775cb7941f35ac9918efc481d4da7a89966d/giddy-2.3.0.tar.gz (57kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 8.2MB/s 
Collecting inequality>=1.0.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/0f/9ed2d097f29160d0c873f33ffc0b9806c1083e3611acb2143eb66adcf580/inequality-1.0.0.tar.gz
Collecting pointpats>=2.1.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/57/29/51bf19dc4452c1429f15335574642bfd5cb672ddbacf8a95c69967ff84b1/pointpats-2.1.0.tar.gz
Collecting segregation>=1.2.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/69/288da08dde201dc250d6dadf6a9ad035e1a5d8b3bdc20b71c2874482d488/segregation-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (110kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 24.7MB/s 
Collecting spaghetti>=1.4.1
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b8/52/700971b94b37193cfb86fe804541d7ed78015a72275cfb4c8c499bfe6b2b/spaghetti-1.4.2.post2-py3-none-any.whl (41kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 7.2MB/s 
Collecting mgwr>=2.1.1
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/21/38/978bd3f72f5376866d37b9155ea67fad9f0bace4e274569b9e0a19df6c4d/mgwr-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (44kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 7.4MB/s 
Collecting spglm>=1.0.7
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/45/5cacaa01f2084162976ab6519a5b13db881363592b400d5c91f1c6abc969/spglm-1.0.7.tar.gz
Collecting spint>=1.0.6
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/68/ed/39822aec1aedd46a2c9eb044e36ab9841f745b3a975074fcce13f58107b9/spint-1.0.6-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting spreg>=1.0.4
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/70/30c5685900505b43444b6c9230eb06f082ea3ec456a5bb7e00e00cef306a/spreg-1.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (264kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 266kB 22.2MB/s 
Collecting spvcm>=0.3.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b4/c9/43fb98bc60728b76fceee175119a1ff7e5033ed9012d07570e34a2a19a8f/spvcm-0.3.0.tar.gz (5.7MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 5.7MB 13.3MB/s 
Collecting tobler>=0.2.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/29/21/5f6228878b985a6518cbad432cd0db6bebbee4934600b63dbca2dbae773b/tobler-0.3.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting mapclassify>=2.2.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/91/b5/6b54f40901d89f2ce30cf2d8110dd57658db3e95db79baba6706d7588691/mapclassify-2.2.0.tar.gz (47kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 7.9MB/s 
Collecting splot>=1.1.2
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/83/1c/afb3e3eeeda4eef065f0b3249ca74cbcc44af3bc59ddb5a21b5445753955/splot-1.1.3.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.25 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from pysal) (1.24.3)
Collecting python-dateutil<=2.8.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/17/c62faccbfbd163c7f57f3844689e3a78bae1f403648a6afb1d0866d87fbb/python_dateutil-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (226kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 235kB 46.4MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.11 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from libpysal>=4.2.2->pysal) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from libpysal>=4.2.2->pysal) (1.18.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from libpysal>=4.2.2->pysal) (1.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: bs4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from libpysal>=4.2.2->pysal) (0.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from libpysal>=4.2.2->pysal) (2.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from libpysal>=4.2.2->pysal) (2.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from esda>=2.2.1->pysal) (0.22.2.post1)
Collecting quantecon
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/72/15/7649ba1f5ad5adc78efbda71d5f1dd15f0edf4a0dead41ba048b7d7e5335/quantecon-0.4.7-py3-none-any.whl (229kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 235kB 46.7MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from pointpats>=2.1.0->pysal) (3.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: geopandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from segregation>=1.2.0->pysal) (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: seaborn in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from segregation>=1.2.0->pysal) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from segregation>=1.2.0->pysal) (4.38.0)
Collecting watermark
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/fe/3ed83b6122e70dce6fe269dfd763103c333f168bf91037add73ea4fe81c2/watermark-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting rtree
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/56/6f/f1e91001d5ad9fa9bed65875152f5a1c7955c5763168cae309546e6e9fda/Rtree-0.9.4.tar.gz
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I even checked the logs, the same was printed. Any help, please.

Colab uses python3 only (for those who are about to suggest pip3 install pysal).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The traceback indicates that the error is not coming from `pysal`, but from `rtree`.

The first Google result for "rtree install error" is [this github thread](https://github.com/Toblerity/rtree/issues/120) which contains [this answer](https://github.com/Toblerity/rtree/issues/120#issuecomment-564126725), indicating that rtree installation requires `libspatialindex`.

With that in mind, you can run the following to install pysal in Colab:

```
!apt install libspatialindex-c4v5
!pip install pysal
```